# OpenGL FBO Returns Black Screen

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, fbo

I'm having a bit of trouble with my frame buffers in my OpenGL C++ application. There are no errors thrown (I get GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE when I call glCheckFramebufferStatus), however when I render my FBO texture all I see is a black screen. I've searched for numerous hours and redone it multiple times to no avail, so I'm finally turning to you guys for some help. Below is all the relevant code. I hope you guys can spot something that my tired eyes couldn't. Thank you.

Initialization code:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

m_texture = new Texture(width, height);
//glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture->GetID());

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture->GetID(), 0);

glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_depth);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depth);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_depth);

GLuint status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
CheckError(status);
```

Texture init code:

```
unsigned char* imageData = fileName != "" ? stbi_load(fileName.c_str(), &width, &height, &numComponents, 4) : 0;

if (imageData == NULL && fileName != "")
    std::cerr << "Texture loading failed for texture: " << fileName << std::endl;

glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

if (fileName != "") stbi_image_free(imageData);
```

Texture bind code:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
```

Framebuffer bind code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
glViewport(0, 0, m_width, m_height);
```

Main code:

```
    fbo.BindFramebuffer();
    display.Clear(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    fboShader.Bind();
    fboShader.Update(transform2, camera);
    texture.Bind(0);
    mesh2.Draw();

    display.Bind();
    display.Clear(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f, 1.0f);

    shader.Bind();
    shader.Update(transform, camera);
    fbo.BindFramebufferTexture(0);
    mesh3.Draw();
```

FBO shader code
Fragment:

```
#version 330

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying vec3 normal0;
varying vec3 position0;

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main()
{
    outputColor = vec4(normal0, 1.0);
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(normal0, 1.0);    
}
```

Vertex:

```
#version 330

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 texCoord;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec2 texCoord0;
varying vec3 normal0;
varying vec3 position0;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0);  
    texCoord0 = texCoord;
    normal0 = (transform * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    position0 = gl_Position.xyz;
}
```

What I should see is a box (mesh3) with a monkeyhead the color of its normals (mesh2) and red background on it, but all I get is black. I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Hard to tell since there's quite a bit of code, but it's not entirely clear how it's all connected, and we don't see all of it. For example, what does `display.Clear()` do? Does it delete the color as well as the depth buffer? Are your shaders compiling? They shouldn't, because they would be compiled as core profile shaders based on the `#version 330`, but they are not compatible with the core profile (which needs `in` and `out` instead of `attribute` and `varying`).

Comment: They do compile, strangely enough. If I change the version to 120 or something, would simply writing to gl_FragColor suffice? I never saw why it wouldn't, but all the tutorials I have ever seen use the out variable. The Clear function simply clears the depth and color buffer, setting glClearColor to the values passed in.

Comment: Make sure that the FBO texture is not bound to a texture unit while drawing to the FBO.

Comment: Already checked that, sadly that doesn't do the trick. I'm really not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Is it a problem if the FBO texture is unbound when I call glFramebufferTexture2D? Because if the texture is bound (glBindTexture) and I call that, I get a GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT. As far as I know, I should glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) before I can glFramebufferTexture2D, but I could be incorrect. I've been stuck on this issue for a while..

Comment: I actually got it working, but I am not sure how. I am coming from many years of Java/C#/other languages to C++, so it may be something to do with how I'm structuring my code. In my fbo class I have a pointer to my texture class. All the same code is run, but if I take the texture code and just put it in my FBO class the fbo works fine. But when I have it in the pointer to the class, it doesn't work. Strange. I'd like to get this working so I can have all the teture methods available for my fbo class. Also, I used a pointer because the Texture class does the GL stuff in the constructor. Ideas?